# Django Rest Framewrok: got KeyError when write test for creating (post) nested serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-tests

I'm try to write test for creating sales data.
But keep getting KeyError: 'content' when running python manage.py test.

The test is to ensure user can add/create sales data with its details (nested)
with [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) as reference to create writeable nested serializers

models.py

```
# abstract base table for transactions
class Base_transaction(models.Model):
    is_paid_off = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    pass

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


# sales table to store surface level sales information
# consist of sales_id as pk, customer_name, sub_total, discount, user_id,
# total, is_paid_off, created_at, updated_at
class Sales(Base_transaction):
    sales_id = models.BigAutoField(
        primary_key=True,
        unique=True
    )
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    customer_contact = models.CharField(max_length=13, blank=True)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        null=True,
        db_column='user_id'
    )

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.sales_id} at {self.created_at} | Lunas={self.is_paid_off}'

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'sales'


# sales_detail table store the detail of sales per sparepart
# consist of sales_detail_id as pk, quantity, individual_price, total_price
# sales_id
class Sales_detail(models.Model):
    sales_detail_id = models.BigAutoField(
        primary_key=True,
        unique=True
    )
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    is_grosir = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sales_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Sales,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        db_column='sales_id'
    )
    sparepart_id = models.ForeignKey(
        'Sparepart',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        db_column='supplier_id'
    )

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.sales_id} - {self.sparepart_id}'
```

serializers.py

```
class SalesDetailSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sparepart = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='sparepart_id.name')

    class Meta:
        model = Sales_detail
        fields = ['sales_detail_id', 'sparepart', 'quantity', 'is_grosir']


class SalesSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    content = SalesDetailSerializers(many=True, source='sales_detail_set')

    class Meta:
        model = Sales
        fields = ['sales_id', 'customer_name', 'customer_contact', 'is_paid_off', 'content']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        details = validated_data.pop('content')

        sales = Sales.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for detail in details:
            Sales_detail.objects.create(sales_id=sales, **detail)
        return sales
```

test.py

```
class SalesAddTestCase(APITestCase):
    sales_url = reverse('sales_add')

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        # Setting up sparepart data
        for i in range(3):
            Sparepart.objects.create(
                name=f'random name{i}',
                partnumber=f'0Y3AD-FY{i}',
                quantity=50,
                motor_type='random m',
                sparepart_type='random s',
                price=5400000,
                grosir_price=5300000,
                brand_id=None
            )

        self.spareparts = Sparepart.objects.all()

        # Creating data that gonna be use as input
        self.data = {
            'customer_name': 'someone',
            'customer_contact': '085634405602',
            'is_paid_off': False,
            'content': [
                {
                    'sparepart': self.spareparts[1].sparepart_id,
                    'quantity': 1,
                    'is_grosir': False,
                },
                {
                    'sparepart': self.spareparts[0].sparepart_id,
                    'quantity': 30,
                    'is_grosir': True,
                }
            ]
        }

    def test_user_successfully_add_sales(self) -> None:
        """
        Ensure user can add new sales data with it's content
        """
        response = self.client.post(self.sales_url, self.data, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        self.assertEqual(response.data['customer_name'], 'someone')
        self.assertEqual(len(response.data['content']), 2)
```

The view i'm using generics.CreateAPIView

the expected response would be the same as self.data with sparepart field became the name of that sparepart.
The example below using random data to give some context

```
{
'customer_name': 'someone',
'customer_contact': '085456105311',
'is_paid_off': False,
 'content': [
       {
         'sparepart': 'something1', # the name of sparepart 1
         'quantity': 5,
         'is_grosir': False,
       },
       {
          'sparepart': 'something2', # the name of sparepart 2
          'quantity': 3,
          'is_grosir': False,
       }]
}
```

i tried to change `sparepart` in content to = `self.spareparts[1]` but now give *type* *error Object of type Sparepart is not JSON serializable*, change it to `self.spareparts[1].name` gives same KeyError as before (content).

i suspect the error because sparepart field is `readonlyfield` in `SalesDetailSerializer` then i change it to `charfield`, but still got same KeyError

I'm really confused what make this error occur in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:

1. `sparepart` field in `SalesDetailSerializers` is ReadOnly and cannot be used for my purpose.
2. `content` field on `SalesSerializers` using argument source `sales_detail_set`. I don't know why but the `content` key field in validated_data became `sales_detail_set` not `content`.

My Solutions:

1. Because i already write a test to ensure user can get list of sales with it's detail which required `sparepart` field to show sparepart name, i can't change it. Instead i create another serializer named `SalesDetailPostSerializers` and `SalesPostSerializers` Like this.

```
class SalesDetailPostSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Sales_detail
        fields = ['sales_detail_id', 'sparepart_id', 'quantity', 'is_grosir']


class SalesPostSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    content = SalesDetailPostSerializers(many=True, source='sales_detail_set')

    class Meta:
        model = Sales
        fields = ['sales_id', 'customer_name', 'customer_contact', 'is_paid_off', 'content']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        details = validated_data.pop('sales_detail_set')
        sales = Sales.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for details in details:
            Sales_detail.objects.create(sales_id=sales, **details)
        return sales
```

2. in `SalesPostSerializer` change

```
details = validated_data.pop('content')
```

To

```
details = validated_data.pop('sales_detail_set')
```

Then change `sparepart` key name inside `self.data` in test.py to `sparepart_id`

```
'sparepart_id': self.spareparts[1].sparepart_id,
```